# Asp.Net Core Identity 2.2 and Identity Server 4, Changing User Id type results in an error in the db context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

After got [this code sample](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCoreOAuth/tree/master/src/AuthServer) to run successfully, I tried to change the Identity User Id type to Guid:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I got error in the database context

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

saying:

> The type 'AuthServer.Infrastructure.Data.Identity.AppUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in
>   the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'AuthServer.Infrastructure.Data.Identity.AppUser' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

Guessing that Asp.Net Roles are not used by Identity Server in this project, I've tried a workaround by creating an empty AppRole class inheriting from IdentityRole and used it as follows:

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid>
```

Error stopped showing but after deleted migrations folder and recreated a new initial migration, I've got the following error:

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'.
>   Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   GenericArguments[1](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCoreOAuth/tree/master/src/AuthServer), 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TRole'.

So what can be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below steps :

1. Modify the `AppUser` in `AuthServer.Infrastructure` :

   ```
   public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
   {
       // Add additional profile data for application users by adding properties to this class
       public string Name { get; set; }        
   }
   ```
2. Modify the `AppIdentityDbContext` in `AuthServer.Infrastructure`:

   ```
   public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
   {
           ...
   }
   ```
3. Modify the `Startup.cs` in `AuthServer` :

   ```
   services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   ```
4. Rebuild the `AuthServer` project, check whether any error occurs :

   Modify `RegisterResponseViewModel`: `Id = user.Id.ToString();`

   Modify `AccountController.cs`: use `user.Id.ToString()` instead of `user.Id`
5. Delete the Migrations ,  `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` , and then again update database : `dotnet ef database update` . Choose which context with `--context AppIdentityDbContext` in the command .

Comment: Sorry, could not mark this as an answer because I could not yet ensure the code is working. Currently I need to extend the IdentityRole entity because I have a mandatory property to add, but there are two Roles entities, one is supplied by Identity Server and the other is supplied by AspNet Identity, I would like to seed some users and roles, so how can I extend IdentityRole without confusing the application with 'discriminator' columns and so on ?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "discriminator" . Identity server 4 use asp.net identity as user/role management . So what do you mean by two role entities.

Comment: I am extending IdentityRole to AppRole by adding a custom property, when I did that I started to see error while posting my username and password, "discriminator" is a column name added to the table automatically when using such Identity inheritance, there are some questions about this "discriminator" column at stackoverflow and elsewhere, but still could not find recent asp.net core 2+ related.

Comment: Okay, above error happens because at startup.cs I was using services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>() and at AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid> and at AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>. Now I need to see why I am getting two role tables instead of one.